# Key-value storage in c++

Tags: c++

Is there some key value Object in c++ besides STL::map? I want to do something like this

```
bool addSalary( int salaryBonus , string name, storage &store ){

   if ( store[name] ){
      store[name]+=salaryBonus;
   }else{
      store[name]=saalaryBonus;
   }
return true;

}
```

But cant use stl::map , i cant find any build in "object" that would behave like key-value storage.

Comment: Why can't you use `std::map`?

Comment: The standard library has `std::map` (or `std::unordered_map`) for this purpose. If you “can't” use it, please explain what your requirements are and why said containers don't meet them. As your question stands, you're not likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: That entire `addSalary` function is this using `std::map`: `store[name] += salaryBonus;`  So you really need to explain why you can't use `map`, when it does exactly what your code is attempting to do, and with *less* code.

Comment: its forbidden in this task , i am looking for a way how to implement it by myself of something which has simillar functionality.

Comment: @user3706129 - Why is it forbidden?  Are you ready to implement a red-black or 2-3 tree?  Is this a data structures course you're in?  And if this is forbidden, why not list for us what anything else that's forbidden.

Comment: I guess it's your class homework... for a simple map implementation read about hash maps with double hashing

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to check if an entry exists. This is possible with `std::map`. Here is how to do it:

```
store.find(name) != store.end()
```